# Can we have access specifiers inside properties for set and get in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Can we have access specifiers for get/set inside a property in C# ?Please explain with an example and usage and also the benefits and darksides. It was an interview question.

Comment: Guessing because this would be covered by any book on C# in the chapter about properties. Also, I'm sure a google search would have enlightened you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great example of this is typified by this fragment...

```
    public interface IHasInt
    {
        int TheInt { get; }
    }
    public class MyClass : IHasInt
    {
        public int TheInt { get; private set; }
        public MyClass()
        {
            TheInt = 123;
        }
    }
```

In this example, the interface has specified a getter, but not a setter.  So when someone has an instance of the interface, they are only allowed to access the value, but cannot alter it.

The implementing class on the other hand, needs to set the property and also does not want anyone to alter it.  So the property gets...

```
a public getter to abide by the terms of the interface; and
a private setter to allow the class to do its work
```

The benefits are that anyone using an instance of the interface cannot change the class's property (and thereby putting the class into a random state).  Changes to the property can be made only within the class itself because the setter is private.

There are lots of these cases like this in the .NET Framework Library.

As to the 'darkside', if the interface has been poorly designed and clients NEED to change the property, then it will ultimately have to be rewritten.  Also if the setter has been declared 'private' like in the example, it blocks descendant classes from accessing the property, which might result in 'shadow' overriding, and that nearly always results in a mess.

Comment: Garry, that was truly lovely explanation, every word I understood and that answered all my doubts on this question. I am delighted so much, thank you so much for being so down to earth and helping me understand this in the way that I can chew. I am really grateful to you, thank you so much for your time :) I will now happily use this concept wherever applicable. Thank you again Garry. I appreciate it :)

Comment: I had an interview question ALMOST like this last week, but they only wanted the theory part, and I already knew the answer.  Read Skeet!

Comment: Thank you again Garry, that's interesting to know. I answered "yes" to this question as I saw some code having "private set". But honestly don't know the right usage/meaning/drawbacks but I learned it everything from your notes now. Why I was a bit skeptical was, after this question, suddenly the interviewer said, he is done with the interview and the interview ended. Anyway !! I could have answered other questions well too. I am happy that I am learning :) Thank you Garry for your nice simple explanation with example. I like this way of example+usage/need+drawback rather than some texts :(

Answer (score 2):

Yes, access modifiers are valid for `get` and `set`. Something common is having a private or protected `set` so property can be only assigned from class instance members.

> The get and set portions of a property or indexer are called accessors. By default these accessors have the same visibility, or access level: that of the property or indexer to which they belong. However, it is sometimes useful to restrict access to one of these accessors. Typically, this involves restricting the accessibility of the set accessor, while keeping the get accessor publicly accessible

Take a look to [Restricting Accessor Accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx) on MSDN article for more infomation about this topic.

Comment: Hi, sorry to say, I have already had a look at this, but didn't understood anything :( Asusual MSDN confuses. Can I have private set and public get explicitly on the same property ? Or any other combination ?

Comment: @Divine the link is very clear about how to understand and use modifiers in accessors, have you read it carefully?

Comment: BTW +1 for the good link, that's at least the best reference for the OP (and others having the same problem).

Comment: King, I hardly read MSDN, most of the times, like it is for many people, my experience or feedback for MSDN is not healthy. It might be, useful for highly experienced developers like you or others here. However, I am still new to programming and stuffs basically and don't understand many from MSDN but from other few blogs

Comment: @Divine In the page from the link, you should notice this line `...By default these accessors have the same visibility, or access level: that of the property or indexer to which they belong.` and the `Restrictions on Access Modifiers on Accessors`. That's all to understand.

Comment: King, I don't have any offense, MSDN, perhaps, may be good for experienced developers. Really I find it hard many times, albeit, I must concede that, it is really understandable on certain areas. I am not an experienced developer, slowly trying to get my passion on development. Sorry if that was offensive. I am trying to learn. Really Garry's explanation helped me a lot, the way I exactly could understand. I am thankful to you all again.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that if the property has *both* a getter and a setter (`get` accessor and `set` accessor), then an extra access modifier is allowed on only *one* of these accessors, and the accessibility of the accessor in question most be *more* restricted than the accessibility of the entire property.

Here's an example:

```
class ContainingType
{
  public int MyProp
  {
    get
    {
      // code here, must return something
    }

    private set
    {
      // code here, may use special parameter 'value'
    }
  }
}
```

In the example the getter is (still) `public`, like the entire property, while the setter has a more restricted access, here `private`.

Think of a property as a pair of methods where one method may have a more restricted access level than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can have access specifiers for get,set but there are some rules:

- The accessibility level on the accessor must be **more** restrictive than the accessibility level on the property
- You can use accessor modifiers only if the property or indexer has **both** set and get accessors. In this case, the modifier is permitted on only **one** of the two accessors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  we can use access specifiers for get/set inside a property in C#.
if we not use the access specifier with the get/set property, that case we can not access values of related property, i.e. get/set values.